# Default Implementation of Link List and Binary Tree using smart pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

The link list is generally implemented as

```
template <typename T>
struct ListNode {
 T data;
 shared_ptr<ListNode<T>> next; //-->why not unique pointer here ?
};
```

while for Binary Tree ,

```
template <typename T>
struct BinaryTreeNode {
 T data;
 unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>> left, right; //-->why not shared pointer here ?
};
```

why can we not use unique_ptr for List and shared_ptr for Binary Tree ?

Comment: *"The link list is generally implemented as"* Who says that?

Comment: On the `shared_ptr`, probably to make it harder to accidentally delete the rest of the list when you remove a node. Personally I'm not a fan of smart pointers in nodes. I don't think nodes should be smart enough to manage the memory of their fellow nodes. That's the list or tree's job.